# How to insert database from datagridview not duplicate value. [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, duplicates

I add data to datagridview, check duplicate value from datagridview and insert to database.

**Ex.**

```
Datagridview
Code:
130027646001
130027646002
130027646003

After add data to datagridview
Code:
130027646001
130027646002
130027646003
130027646004
130027646005

After to insert to database Result
130027646001
130027646002
130027646003
130027646001
130027646002
130027646003
130027646004
130027646005

But I want Result
130027646001
130027646002
130027646003
130027646004
130027646005
```

i want insert to database don't duplicate value only 130027646004,130027646005 to database.
i try write code 2 type But doesn't work all.

**This Code (Type one):**

```
    Dim sqlC As String = ""
    Dim DT As New DataTable
    Dim sendStatus As Integer

    sqlC = "Select c.* "
    sqlC &= "FROM Clother c 
    sqlC &= "WHERE c.No=" & tClother
    DT = FShowData(sqlItem)

    If DT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To DgvItem.Rows.Count - 1
            If DgvItem.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value <> DT.Rows(i).Item("Code") Then
                sendStatus = FuncInsert(CStr(DgvItem.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value))
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

**This Code (Type Two):**
i write code but error "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.Couldn't store <130027646001> in No Column.  Expected type is Int32."

```
        Dim sqlC As String = ""
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        Dim sendStatus As Integer

        sqlC = "Select c.* "
        sqlC &= "FROM Clother c 
        sqlC &= "WHERE c.No=" & tClother
        DT = FShowData(sqlItem)

If DgvItem.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To DgvItem.Rows.Count - 1
                If (CStr(DgvItem.Rows(i).Cells("Code").Value) <> "") Then
                    Dim dr As DataGridViewRow
                    dr = DgvItem.Rows(i)
                    DT.TableName = "Code"
                    If DT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        For j As Integer = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1
                            If CStr(DgvItem.Rows(i).Cells("Code").Value) <> CStr(DT.Rows(j).Item("Code")) Then
                                sendStatus = FuncInsert(CStr(DgvItem.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value))
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If

                    DT.Rows.Add(dr.Cells("Code").Value).ToString() >> Error Line: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.Couldn't store <130027646001> in No Column.  Expected type is Int32.

                End If
            Next
        End If
        DT.Dispose()
        DT = Nothing
```

**Table Clother**

```
Field Type
Code  nvarchar
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I agree with Mitch, this is slightly difficult to understand. But have you tried using a `SELECT DISTINCT`? You can read more on it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use autoincrement & primary key in your database table? Inserting duplicate items seems like you don't have an unique value for each field.

If you have a table like this:

Column1 |
1
2
3
4

And you want to add the value AUTOMATICLY you with 1 value after the current value you use NEXTVAL. I might now be so explicit but i hope you get the idea.

You can check this link too : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls1016.htm